# Creating a template type using template parameters

Tags: c++

My template knowledge is a bit rusty in this case.

Inside class `A` (a templated class with 2 template parameters, `T1` and `T2`), how can one correctly declare the function parameter `myType` used in `f()` method below:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class A
{
  void f(T1<T2> myType);
  void g(T2 myType2)
}
```

**Edit**: when used, `T2` is a non-templated type, but `T1` is a templated type.

Reason for this is that I have use-cases where `T2` can be used alone, without `T1`. But still, I would like to define `T2` depending on `T1` (to make the dependencies clear).

Comment: What do you expect `void f(int<char> myType);` to do? This makes no sense.

Comment: Please show a simple intended use case.

Comment: Your confusion may come from your sloppy use of terms. There is no such thing as a "templated type". There are *types*, and there are *templates*. Types aren't templates, and templates aren't types. Types may *result* from (the specialization of) a template, but it's important to distinguish the template from its specializations.

Comment: Agree, I should not have used templated type. Cheers for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> T2 is a non-templated type, but T1 is a templated type

In this case, `T1` should be a template template parameter.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
template<template<typename> class T1, typename T2>
struct S {
    void f(T1<T2>) {}
    void g(T2) {}
};

template<typename>
struct T {};

int main() {
    S<T, int> s;
    s.f(T<int>{});
    s.g(42);
}
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) for further details.

---

> But still, I would like to define T2 depending on T1 (to make the dependencies clear)

If you want to be clear about the dependency, you can also enforce it by using a partial specialization similar to the one in the following example:

```
template<typename>
struct S;

template<template<typename> class T1, typename T2>
struct S<T1<T2>> {
    void f(T1<T2>) {}
    void g(T2) {}
};

template<typename>
struct T {};

int main() {
    S<T<int>> s;
    s.f(T<int>{});
    s.g(42);
}
```